# How can I delete all my photos on my iPhone on Windows?

Tags: iphone, ios, photos

I want to delete all my photos from my iPhone 4s running iOS 7.0.3 but it wont let me. I have tried in numerous ways, but they don't work.

1. I don't want to delete them one-by-one.
2. Usage → Camera and Photos, swipe Camera Roll and delete does **not** work on iOS 7.
3. I tried using Image Capture on my computer, and my device shows up on the left, but there are no image files.
4. I tried manually deleting them from my iPhone files on my Windows 7 PC but it wont let me delete them.

Comment: Are you referring to photos taken on the device, photos synced through iTunes, photos from your Photo Stream or photos from a Shared Photo Stream?

Comment: I am referring to the photos on my iPhone. I can sync through iTunes also, but it still wont let me remove them.